# Error in seq_len

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
> head (data)
                                                             verb_object SESSION_ID transactionID sequenceID eventID items
1:                               34D89F927092290A5DA9B108F7020C19 SELECT   36652675          2058   36652675       1   OV1
2: 15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL   38763251            90   38763251       1   OV2
3: D6941F85A1763F1F2D27B8F032D6411C86D4A5200512D65F381052C7D42BF57F CALL   40257471            63   40257471       1   OV3
4:                               E768D36C813FD14157B06474F345EAFC SELECT   40897086         39475   40897086       1   OV4
5: 15873DB37BF80750C70B68A8778B9DC01D548B6D06E3BF92CADAFF289B3FCAEE CALL   40907760            57   40907760       1   OV2
6:                               8067DE5FF5089BE6EC9D213F42525FC3 SELECT   40928334         29697   40928334       1   OV5
```

When I run the following commands:

```
> data <- data[, -(1:2)]
> rownames(data) <- as.character (seq_len(nrow(data)) )
Error in seq_len(nrow(data)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(nrow(data)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Why is it? Another user of the same data in different computer didn't get it.

Comment: That's a data table (not a data frame).  What are you trying to do?  Row names on data tables are not allowed.

Comment: It is a dataframe. > class (data)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

Comment: Yep, and it's also a data table, for which row names are not allowed.  What are you trying to do?   To get a regular data frame use `setDF(data)`

Comment: The real problem starts with  `data <- data[, -(1:2)]`.  It doesn't work the same in a data table as a data frame.  You aren't removing columns with that call.  Have a look at `data` after the call.  Convert to data frame and you should be fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard Scriven:
When using

```
> setDF(data)
> data <- data[, -(1:2)]
> rownames(data) <- as.character (seq_len(nrow(data)) )
```

I get the required result:

```
> head (data)
  transactionID sequenceID eventID items
1          2058   36652675       1   OV1
2            90   38763251       1   OV2
3            63   40257471       1   OV3
4         39475   40897086       1   OV4
5            57   40907760       1   OV2
6         29697   40928334       1   OV5
```